# make python file as executable file. modules: tkinter, pandas

Tags: python, exe

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def final():
    Tk().withdraw()  # Close the root window
    in_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print(in_path)
    df = pd.read_csv(in_path)
    newList = df['delivery_price'].tolist()
    print(newList)

    output = list(map(lambda elem: float(elem.split()[0]), newList))
    print()
    print("Your total amount is: " + str(sum(output)))
    button.destroy()
    label = Label(root, text="Your total amount is \n" + str(sum(output)))
    label.pack()


    root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Find total", command=final)
button.pack()
button.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
root.title("Sherpa")
root.geometry('200x200+600+250')
root.mainloop()
```

I wrote this small program which extracts a specific column from a CSV file which the user chooses.
the column consists of text and float:
"AUD 31.33"

Then, it gets rid of the string, and save it as the only float in a list.
In the end, I get the total amount of the column.

I used TKinter for the gui:

when I run it in pyCharm:

1) a small window appears with a button "find total"

2) after clicking "find total", it ask for the .csv file

3) user chooses the file.

4) the total amount is displayed in the small window.

That's what I really wanted with the program. but now I want to make it .exe so that I don't have to open pycharm all the time. 
I tried py2installer, it gets compiled but it doesn`t run. Is there any format to follow to make GUI apps that are executable.
Or do I have to make changes in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see what the error is that you get? (Sometimes difficult with exe-files, because the window closes after the error. I sometimes try to make a screenshot at the right moment).

I had a problem with the PyQt module when compiling a script with Tkinter using pyinstaller. What worked for me was the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2857#issuecomment-331975770). It's copying the `qwindows.dll` file to the directory `\platforms\qwindows.dll`in your pyinstaller output dir (`..\dist\<your program.\platforms\qwindows.dll`).

Comment: I do not have "/platform" directory. Do I have to add any main method to make it work or something? I am using python 3.7. any other mod to use to convert to exe?

Comment: Do you have the following directory and file: `\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll`? If so, copy the qwindows.dll to \platforms (you have to create the platforms dir). I don't know if you have this problem, since I don't know what your error is. But this seems to happen often with pyinstaller en tkinter.

Comment: An alternative to Pyinstaller is py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/). But I've never used that one.

Comment: i don`t have PyQt5 directory at all. Can you check my code, if I have to change anything?

Comment: Okay, then you obviously have a different problem. Since your code works fine in PyCharm, there shouldn't be anything wrong with it. The problem probably lies somewhere in the compiling with pyinstaller. Do you see any obvious errors when running pyinstaller or when you execute the exe file?

Comment: when i click the exe file. error is: ModuleNoTFoundError: no module named 'pandas'. Failed to execute script <my_filename>

Comment: Then somehow it didn't include pandas when compiling your script. Are you running pyinstaller from a python environment in which you have installed pandas (so the same as you use in pycharm)?

Comment: i installed pyinstaller with pip.
open cmd, change directory to python file.
type "pyinstaller --onefile total.py"
it creates 2 new folder,dist and build. 
Inside dist, when i click exe file,, that above error occurs. and what did you mean "Are you running pyinstaller from a python environment in which you have installed pandas (so the same as you use in pycharm)?"

Comment: Normally, Pyinstaller would find all modules needed to execute your code (so also pandas in your case), and import them to create the exe. In your case, this doesn't work correctly. One of the reasons could be that you have more then 1 python environment on your system, and that the one pyinstaller uses doesn't have pandas installed. Did you for example use Anaconda to install python?

Comment: ok. it was my bad. I installed pandas in pycharm from the pycharm settings, but it was not added in the environment. thats why it was not getting pandas when it was getting compiled. Just pip installed pandas with cmd. now its working fine. Thanks for helping me figure it out.

Comment: No problem, happy to help